# Valid iframe-like technique

Tags: iframe, html

I recently found out over the weekend that iframes are not valid in XHTML strict.  What would the correct way to refresh certain content then? A friend said just use divs and have JavaScript refresh them, is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is right in a sense. You can achieve a similar effect to iframes by using AJAX to load a page into a `<div>` container. The problem is that AJAX requests are usually limited within the same domain, so you will not be able to load other websites. You can load other pages from your own domain though.

AJAX is ridiculously easy with jQuery. Check out this function:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
<div id="externalcontent">This text will be replaced.</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#externalcontent').load('separate_pages/page2.html');
</script>
```

This would be kind of pointless  as you could just load the content using server-side methods, but it shows how easy loading another page can be with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Use XHTML Frameset

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/html4strict/frameset-example.htm

Comment: Does it have to by XHTML? 
What about <!DOCTYPE html> (HTML5 Doctype)?
Why is it so important it uses the XHTML 1.0 Strict Doctype?

Comment: That's what the client wants so that's want the client gets.  Iframes still would not validate in HTML 5 because they have been deprecated.

Comment: They're not deprecated, `<iframe>` even received new features in HTML5. However if you client wants XHTML Strict then this isn't the solution for you (unless they can be persuaded otherwise - which may be advisable)

Comment: My mistake, I just asked my web design professor a few minutes ago and he said they were deprecated but I guess he meant only for strict? I did see the new features for I iframes in HTML 5 though.  I may try and persuade them to let me convert their site to 5, just means more money :)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is good. Check out jQuery (http://jquery.com/) for easier DOM manipulation!

Comment: You can use basically any element. divs have good basic attributes for your problem though!